# Working on vertical sliders need to drag up and down individually

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular12

[image]# Working on vertical sliders need to drag up and down individually but If I pull first on all sliders also moving. and button resetAllSliders  should also working individually  button applyAllSliders need to apply changes.

**HTML FILE**

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div *ngFor="let slider of sliders; let i = index" class="slider">
      <input type="range" [(ngModel)]="slider.value" (input)="onSliderChange(slider, i)" />
      <button (click)="resetSlider(slider)">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button (click)="resetAllSliders()">Reset All</button>
    <button (click)="applyAllSliders()">Apply All</button>
  </div>
```

**TS File**

```
// src/app/slider-app/slider-app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider-app',
  templateUrl: './slider-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider-app.component.css']
})
export class SliderAppComponent {
  sliders: { value: number }[] = Array(3).fill({ value: 10 });

  onSliderChange(slider: { value: number }, index: number) {
    // Handle individual slider value change
    console.log(`Slider ${index} value changed to ${slider.value}`);
  }
  resetSlider(slider: { value: number }) {
    // Reset the individual slider to its default value
    slider.value = 10; // You can set the default value here
  }

  resetSliders() {
    // Reset all sliders to their default values
    this.sliders.forEach(slider => {
      slider.value = 10;
    });
  }

  applySliders() {
    
    console.log('Applying slider values:', this.sliders.map(slider => slider.value));
  }
}
```

**please help**

**above code needs drag up down individually   **

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate these sliders among themselves.

In your component, add a `name` property on top of the existing `value` property.

##### example.component.ts

```js
type Slider = {
  name: string;
  value: number;
};

@Component({
 ...
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  public sliders: Slider[] = [
    {name: '1', value: 5},
    {name: '2', value: 4},
    {name: '3', value: 10}
  ];
}
```

##### example.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let slider of sliders">
  <input type="range" [name]="slider.name" [(ngModel)]="slider.value">
</div>
```